# How to get data from db using json format inside componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

I have a set of data in mongodb in Json format, I want to get that out and populate it in react js for my pie chart, can you please help me how to do that. Below the code I have. In this I get the data from the DB using fetch and store it in ddts from this.state, but I am not able to get all the data from that ddts and populate it in the data list for the pie chart. I have the data in json format in the db as

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"_id":"5d33f8bdd7f819c52b4406aa","total":"51","resolved":"20","assigned":"15","open":"0","new":"1","info":"2","closed":"0","unrepro":"6","duped":"3","junk":"0"}]}
```

Below is the `react.js` frontend code. Can anyone please help me populate the date to display in the pie chart.

```
  componentDidMount() {
  this.getDataFromDb();
  if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000);
      this.setState({intervalIsSet: interval});
  }
  }
  getDataFromDb = () => {fetch('http://172.24.78.202:3002/api/ddts')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(res => this.setState({ ddts: res.data }));
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb();
    if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
    let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 1000);
    this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
  }
  const { ddts } = this.state;
  const { resolved } = ddts.map((dat) => {dat.resolved})
  const chartConfig = {
    type: "pie",
    data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        hoverBorderColor: "#ffffff",
        data: [{resolved}, 24, 7.5, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(0, 146, 0, 1.1)",
          "rgba(0,123,255,0.5)",
          "rgba(0,123,255,0.1)",
          "rgba(0,123,255,0.1)",
          "rgba(0,123,255,0.1)",
          "rgba(0,123,255,0.1)",
          "rgba(0,123,255,0.1)"
        ]
      }
     ],
     labels: ["Resolved", "Assigned", "New", "Closed", "Junk", 
               "Duped", "Unreproduciable"]
     },
     options: {
    ...{
      legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
          padding: 25,
          boxWidth: 20
        }
      },
      cutoutPercentage: 0,
      tooltips: {
        custom: false,
        mode: "index",
        position: "nearest"
      }
    },
    ...this.props.chartOptions
  }
};
 new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, chartConfig);
}
render() {
  const { ddts } = this.state;
  const { title } = this.props;
return (
  <Card small className="h-100">
    <CardHeader className="border-bottom">
      <h6 className="m-0">{title}</h6>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardBody className="d-flex py-0">
      <canvas
        height="220"
        ref={this.canvasRef}
        className="blog-users-by-device m-auto"
      />
 </CardBody>
```

Comment: Looks like copied and pasted the code incorrectly or you have syntax issues?  Are you able to get data from your endpoint correctly?  Is it just a problem of with the chart or is the problem fetching the data?

Comment: The problem is to populate the data in the chart from db

Comment: Basically I have the data from mongoDB in json key object type, I want a code that can extract the values and store it in a varaible. The data from the DB is like this : ''' {"success":true,"data":[{"_id":"5d33f8bdd7f819c52b4406aa","total":"51","resolved":"20","assigned":"15","open":"0","new":"1","info":"2","closed":"0","unrepro":"6","duped":"3","junk":"0"}]} '''
In this I need to get the value "total" : 51 out and store it in a variable  total and use it as data for the pie chart to display in the the pie chart format.